# ForceMode in AddTorque in Unity game development

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, torque

In UNITY game development platform while programming in C# I came across a method to add torque to component: **public void AddTorque(float x, float y, float z, ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force);**
In this Function what is meant by **ForceMode**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ForceMode is an enumeration. It has 4 values,

ForceMode.Acceleration = Constant change not affected by mass

ForceMode.Force = Constant change which is affected by mass

ForceMode.Impulse = Instant change which is affected by mass

ForceMode.VelocityChange = Instant change which is not affected by mass

For more details, watch the Official Unity tutorial for AddForce. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBDWTjn05eg

Comment: @hkishnani3 this is correct, documentation: [ForceMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html)